# Google Search Console - URL is not on Google: Indexing errors

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console, google-index

I'm new in search marketing.I am trying to index one of the site, while inspecting the home page url in search console, it shows "**URL is not on Google: Indexing errors**" and under Indexing Allowed, it shows "**No: 'noindex' detected in 'robots' meta tag**"
I have cross checked the meta robots robots in which found this tag

Also, in robots.txt file, nothing is blocking.
No able to understand what is wrong with the site and why Search console displaying such things in coverage issue. The site is on wordpress.
Please help me to understand this. Here is the site link - https://www.homeofvapes.com/

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case your question has already been asked and answered there: [Website not properly indexed by Google search console says "'noindex' detected in 'robots' meta tag" while this is not the case](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133751/)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the message “URL is not on google: indexing errors” it means that Google has either removed the URL from their index because they could not access it or it's not in their index because when they first tried to crawl it was not available.

Comment: This might be the case, as when it was on staging (under development) we marked it as Noindex and nofollow, might be at that time Google tried to reaching to my site. But now it is start crawling and indexing.